# Bigquery select distinct values

Tags: google-bigquery

How to select distinct values in Google Bigquery?

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cc_info
FROM user
WHERE date = ?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
SELECT cc_info
FROM user
WHERE date = ?
GROUP BY cc_info
```

Comment: And if this solution stops working as your tables grow larger, you can replace `GROUP BY` with `GROUP EACH BY` to increase the scalability.

Comment: is it possible to do select * from table group by *?

Answer (score 6):

Simply use group by,

```
SELECT cc_info
FROM user
WHERE date = ?
GROUP BY cc_info
```

If you want to COUNT over DISTINCT values you can use,

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cc_info)
FROM user
WHERE date = ?
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using `group by`

```
SELECT cc_info
FROM user
WHERE date = ?
group by cc_info
```

Answer (score 4):

For all who have come to find the DISTINCT method in BigQuery, and who needs to use unique field feature for tables having large columns, using `GROUP BY` as mentioned by [tning](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2848780/tning) won't be possible.

As of 2020, BigQuery has [DISTINCT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_modifiers) modifier. You need to wrap your query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT usr.cc_info
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM user
  WHERE date = ?
) usr
```

This could be very handy for people shifting from other SQL products.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cc_info)
FROM user
WHERE date = ?
```

is **NOT** the right query, because `DISTINCT` is a statistical approximation and is not guaranteed to be exact. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#countdistinct

So better approach is

```
select EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(cc_info) from user where date = ?
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Normal distinct uses hyper log log algorithm to count distinct over distributed machines. Depending on your data if some approximation is alright, COUNT provides much better performance compared to EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT. I really appreciate how complex algorithm runs behind the scene for a simple COUNT DISTINCT statement. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#exact_count_distinct

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to achieve your goal (in case anyone else needs it) which works in the current BigQuery 2020.

```
SELECT colname FROM table1
UNION DISTINCT 
SELECT colname FROM table2
UNION DISTINCT
.
.
.
SELECT colname FROM tableN
```

My reference was [this article](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-union-queries-in-google-bigquery/).

Answer (score 0):

At present, BigQuery provides the Distinct Counts view by default under the Table Explorer tab