# select distinct values in bigquery using standardsql

Tags: google-bigquery

i want to select multiple columns and group the email with `GROUP BY`

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
      customers.orderCustomerEmail AS email,      
      customers.orderCustomerNumber AS customerNumber,
      customers.billingFirstname AS billingFirstname,
      customers.billingLastname AS billingLastname
FROM dim_customers AS customers
GROUP BY customers.orderCustomerEmail
```

Fails with:

```
Error: SELECT list expression references customers.orderCustomerNumber
       which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [4:7]
```

This is similar to this question [Bigquery select distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611428/bigquery-select-distinct-values)

but it doesn't solve my problem because its a different result adding all columns to `GROUP BY` same with `SELECT DISTINCT`

dim_customer schema:

```
orderCustomerEmail:STRING,
billingFirstname:STRING,
billingLastname:STRING,
orderCustomerNumber:STRING,
OrderNumber:STRING
```

dummy data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T1JZRWni18hhU4tO-9kQqq5Y3hVWgpP-aE7o6ij9bDE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What you mean "it's a different result adding all columns to group by"? Do you have an example of what you want as input and as the result?

Comment: because in bigquery a group by several columns e.g. email and firstname returns 

a@email.com, Alex and
a@email.com, A.

but i just need one result in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you group by some columns, you need to make sure you apply some aggregation function(s) to the rest of the columns. otherwise you get exactly error that you show in your question

Try below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  customers.orderCustomerEmail AS email,      
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(customers.orderCustomerNumber AS customerNumber,
  customers.billingFirstname AS billingFirstname,
  customers.billingLastname AS billingLastname)) AS info
FROM `dim_customers`, UNNEST(customers) AS customers
GROUP BY email
```

or with just simple DISTINCT

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT 
  customers.orderCustomerEmail AS email,      
  customers.orderCustomerNumber AS customerNumber,
  customers.billingFirstname AS billingFirstname,
  customers.billingLastname AS billingLastname
FROM `dim_customers`, UNNEST(customers) AS customers
```

Please note: your question is not specific enough in terms of what exactly output you expect, so above will most likely require some adjustment to your specific needs

**Update**

> i need basically one row per customer (email being the unique identifier, hence the group) the details (number, firstname, lastname) can be taken from the last entry e.g

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `dim_customers` AS (
  SELECT [
    STRUCT('a' AS orderCustomerEmail, 1 AS orderCustomerNumber, 'af' AS billingFirstname, 'al' AS billingLastname),
    STRUCT('a' AS orderCustomerEmail, 4 AS orderCustomerNumber, 'af1' AS billingFirstname, 'al2' AS billingLastname),
    STRUCT('b' AS orderCustomerEmail, 2 AS orderCustomerNumber, 'bf' AS billingFirstname, 'bl' AS billingLastname),
    STRUCT('c' AS orderCustomerEmail, 3 AS orderCustomerNumber, 'cf' AS billingFirstname, 'cl' AS billingLastname)
    ] AS customers UNION ALL
  SELECT [
    STRUCT('a' AS orderCustomerEmail, 1 AS orderCustomerNumber, 'af' AS billingFirstname, 'al' AS billingLastname),
    STRUCT('a' AS orderCustomerEmail, 4 AS orderCustomerNumber, 'af1' AS billingFirstname, 'al2' AS billingLastname),
    STRUCT('b' AS orderCustomerEmail, 2 AS orderCustomerNumber, 'bf' AS billingFirstname, 'bl' AS billingLastname),
    STRUCT('c' AS orderCustomerEmail, 3 AS orderCustomerNumber, 'cf' AS billingFirstname, 'cl' AS billingLastname)
    ] AS customers
)
SELECT
  customers.orderCustomerEmail AS email,      
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(customers.orderCustomerNumber AS customerNumber,
    customers.billingFirstname AS billingFirstname,
    customers.billingLastname AS billingLastname))[OFFSET(0)] AS info
FROM `dim_customers`, UNNEST(customers) AS customers
GROUP BY email
```

**Update**

> below is for updated schema!

dim_customer schema:

> orderCustomerEmail:STRING,
>   billingFirstname:STRING,
>   billingLastname:STRING,
>   orderCustomerNumber:STRING,
>   OrderNumber:STRING

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `dim_customers` AS (
  SELECT 10201 AS orderCustomerNumber, 'a@email.com' AS orderCustomerEmail, 'Alex' AS billingFirstname, 'Miller' AS billingLastname UNION ALL
  SELECT 10202, 'b@email.com', 'Ben', 'Williams' UNION ALL
  SELECT 10203, 'c@email.com', 'Chris', 'Collins' UNION ALL
  SELECT 10204, 'd@email.com', 'David', 'Hems' UNION ALL
  SELECT 10201, 'a@email.com', 'A.', 'Miller' UNION ALL
  SELECT 10201, 'a@email.com', 'A.', 'Miller' UNION ALL
  SELECT 10202, 'b@email.com', 'Ben', 'Williams' UNION ALL
  SELECT 10202, 'b@email.com', 'Bens Father', 'Williams' UNION ALL
  SELECT 10205, 'a@email.com', 'A.', 'Miller' UNION ALL
  SELECT 10206, 'e@email.com', 'Ed', 'Winchell'
)
SELECT info.* FROM (
  SELECT
    orderCustomerEmail AS email, 
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(
      orderCustomerEmail AS email, 
      orderCustomerNumber AS customerNumber,
      billingFirstname AS billingFirstname,
      billingLastname AS billingLastname))[OFFSET(0)] AS info
  FROM `dim_customers`
  GROUP BY email
)
-- ORDER BY email
```

Comment: nice idea with the aggregation, i was struggling at that point to flatten the table out again afterwards, also UNNEST(customers) doesn't work at that point.
in terms of output i need basically one row per customer (email being the unique identifier, hence the group) the details (number, firstname, lastname) can be taken from the last entry e.g.

Comment: I tested it with dummy data and it worked as expected. if you have problem with making above code work  - provide more details on your data and clarify what kind of error you are getting

Comment: i just get a Error: Unrecognized name: customers at [7:33] but also customers is just defined after that.

Comment: so you should show the schema of your table. my assumption of it might was wrong

Comment: see update in my answer  - added totally dummy data so you can play with it - and added selection of only one details entry per customer. hope this gives you better idea of used "technique"

Comment: also update my original question with dummy schema and data, i think it works in your case because you define AS customers in your dummy data

Comment: the schema you updated your question with - totally does not match to the initial query you provided in your question!!!!  anyway - trying to help you one more time  - see update

Comment: I am glad it finally works for you :o). Please consider voting up the answer